# Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process ...\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javaee\javaee-api\5\

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when I updated my dependencies in Android Studio 3.3.1, I receive this error:
Android Studio Version: 3.3.1
Gradle Version: 5.4

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Mohamad\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javaee\javaee-api\5\e3cc17b10ab552219edbe33915e62937e387d0ef\javaee-api-5.jar
```

this is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


configurations {
    implementation.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0-rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10
        versionName "3.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation "androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.20.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.0.5'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.3.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.2.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.2.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.2'
    implementation 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:2.24.0'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
    implementation 'za.co.riggaroo:materialhelptutorial:1.2.0'
    implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.1.1'
    implementation 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:64.2'
    implementation 'org.piwik.sdk:piwik-sdk:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.piwik.java.tracking:piwik-java-tracker:1.2'
    implementation project(':persianmaterialdatetimepicker')
    implementation project(':fullscreendialog')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I clean, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart, but doesn't help...

I saw the questions like this, but those didn't help me.
what can I do? anyone help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this form of problem is about duplicated classes in dependencies and to solve it, just put this piece of code in build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'javaee', module: 'javaee-api'
}
```